# Troubleshooting SQL Server Stack Overflow error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, debugging, stack-overflow

How can I effectively troubleshoot this error?

> The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization.
>   Please simplify the query.
>
> Msg 8621, Level 17, State 2

I've tried to attaching profiling, but I'm not sure I have the right messages selected. I do see the error in there. The Estimated Execution Plan gives this error as well.

The sproc I am calling is just doing a really simple `UPDATE` on one table. There is one `UPDATE` trigger, but I disabled it, yet it still is giving me this error. I even took the same `UPDATE` statement out and manually supplied the values. It doesn't return as fast, and still gives me the error.

**Edit:** 
OK, my generated script is setting the PK. So if I set the PK and another column, I get this error. Any suggestions along those lines?

Comment: Please provide DDL that we can use to reproduce this. Any foreign keys on the table?

Comment: @Daniel - no idea why a -1 but I +1 to even it out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a great number of FK's that were being referenced by this PK. I changed our code not to update that PK any further.

Comment: We had a similar issue. Too many FK's

Answer (score 4):

[There's a microsoft KB article about this.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120723071412/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945896)

Basically it's a bug and you need to update.  I'm assuming you are running SQL Server 2005 sp2?

Comment: I'm running `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3080.00 (Intel X86)`. Not sure what if that version is affected. Edit: ok that is sp2.

Comment: Also, my query isn't "very complex".

Comment: Is there any recursion?  Is there anything else running on the server?

Comment: @Daniel - that is the affected version, FYI

Comment: This also happens on our test and production servers which are running SP4.

Answer (score 1):

**This error frequently appears when the number of foreign keys relating to a table exceeds the Microsoft recommended maximum of 253.**

You can disable the constraints temporarily by the following line of code:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

***YOUR DELETE/UPDATE COMMAND***

and after the executing your command, enable it again as the following:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't always a bug! Sounds like Daniel was able to come to the conclusion that the query wasn't as simple as he originally thought.

[This article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1747c0e8-f675-40eb-a3ab-b11c7f7a3f5a/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-stack-space-during-query-optimization-please-simplify-the-query?forum=transactsql) seems to answer a similar question as the one Daniel had.  I just ran into the same error for a different (legitimate) reason as well.  Dynamic SQL being run on a database with data no one anticipated resulted in a single select statement with hundreds of tables.

Comment: Although this link may answer the question it's best to include the contents of the link in case the link goes dead.